# Two-way binding ngModel from @Input decorator and component parameter?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I am passing some props through Ionic's modal controller to a custom component:

```
async editItem(item:any, index:number) {
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: EditItemComponent,
            componentProps: {
                data: this.data,
                item: item,
            }
        });
        await modal.present();
}
```

Within my custom component, I am using a `Input()` decorator to receive the `componentProps` from the modal.

I have been unable to bind the `data` in my component to a `[(ngModel)]`. I am using an `<ion-input>` to display some of the data inside my `data` object and nothing will appear in the layout.

```
export class EditItemComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() data: any;

    constructor(
        private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.data.name);
    }

    dismiss(data?: any) {
        this.modalCtrl.dismiss(data);
    }

}
```

```
<ion-toolbar class="ion-no-border">
        <ion-list lines="full" class="ion-no-padding ion-no-border">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="stacked">Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="data.name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-toolbar>
```

Is there a different approach I need to take in order to display the prop data in my model?

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.data.name);
        this.YourOtherVariable = this.data;
    }`. try with another variable. and bind it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error being logged? If there is one please provide.

Another possible solution for this one is to add `?` operator to your `ngModel`. I guess it is not rendered at first since your `data` Input might be `null`.

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="data?.name"></ion-input>
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. I forgot to import the Forms module in the modals parent modules.